# Should GPIO pins 13 and 14 be soldered together?

Tags: gpio, hardware

I just bought a new Model A+ board, and noticed that the GPIO pins 13 and 14 (board pins 21 and 23) are soldered together on the backside.  This was not the case with my previous A+ board: see the two compared side-by-side below.

1. Is this an error in the board, or the intended configuration?
2. If this is an error, should I remove the solder before using the board (even if I don't intend to use these pins)?

[image: New vs old board]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No they should **not** be soldered together (this is called a solder bridge). You should initiate a return request. You could cut or rework the trace yourself, but I would still suggest returning it - if you have problems down the road you may not be able to successfully return it if you cut the bridge yourself..

Comment: If you have a good iron, I'd ask support if I can attempt to rework it as that error could literally be solved in seconds with 3 cents-worth of braid rather than the huge hassle and cost of RMA'ing the thing.

Comment: My iron doesn't get hot enough to do the job, so I got in touch with Newark about replacing the Pi.  Thank you both for quick replies!

Answer (score 1):

They shouldn't be soldered together, try returning it and DO NOT use it during the time as something could happen.